# Access specifier for member typedef ignored in function template signature

Tags: c++

In the following code `A::Type` is `private` in `A`.

```
class A {
    typedef int Type;
};

void func(int t, A::Type var)
{
    return;
}
```

Trying to compile with `gcc` gives the following error.

```
test.cpp: In function 'void func(int, A::Type)':
test.cpp:12:21: error: 'typedef int A::Type' is private within this context
 void func(int t, A::Type var)
                     ^~~~
test.cpp:2:17: note: declared private here
     typedef int Type;
                 ^~~~
```

But if I change the first parameter to be a template parameter, like so

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t, A::Type var)
{
    return;
}
```

the access specifier of Type seems to be ignored and this compiles.

At first I suspected it might be a bug in `gcc`, but MSVC 2015 exhibits the same behaviour.

Is this behaviour for some reason required by the C++ standard? If so what is the rationale here?

Comment: Clang 6 complains, too.

Comment: Clang 6.0.0 gives an error too

Comment: @lubgr beat me to it : )

Comment: it also doesnt compile with [gcc6](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i9TiGgyxoj9PTwlD). what gcc version are you using?

Comment: I don't know about GCC, but that *"MSVC 2015 exhibits the same behaviour"* is no surprise. VC++ notoriously didn't implement two-phase lookup properly, for years.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist But your version number is of higher accuracy!

Comment: @StoryTeller Just checked and it compiles even in *conformance mode* (!) of msvc 2017 (toolset 141)

Comment: I am using gcc 6.2.0.

Comment: I just tried it in clang 6.0.0. Gives an error for me as well

Comment: @songyuanyao you need to remove the un-templated version of `func`

Comment: [Reported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/329755/msvc-ignores-access-restrictions-on-template-funct.html) the problem regarding MSVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At first I suspected it might be a bug in gcc,

You suspected correctly. GCC has multiple open bugs about missing accessibility checks in templates, but it is clear that its developers consider those bugs that need to be fixed. Your example is probably covered by [template function specialization: does not respect access specifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR45011), even though that uses a dependent typedef, whereas yours is non-dependent.

> but MSVC 2015 exhibits the same behaviour.

Nobody is going to doubt you if you say MSVC has bugs affecting conformance. :)

Comment: Would it be correct to rephrase the question to "Access specifier ignored in template" so that each time this every day recurring question pop up, we close it with a link to your answer?

Comment: @Oliv There are separate bugs about class templates, and different bugs about different contexts in which access specifiers are not respected. If you want to turn this into one big Q&A here on SO, it would probably need an answer pointing that doesn't single out any individual bug, either by including and categorising all of them, or by not including any of them directly.